# 404 error is displayed while using window.push.state function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url, http-status-code-404

I have a new project with ajax call, in which am able to run a function and change the url using window.push.state. When i try to access the function through the url directly, I am getting a 404 error.

There is no such page. But how can I access the function directly.
I have only an index page. When I go to each url, I have to access different function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no such page.  I have only an index page.

That is your problem.

When you use `pushState` you are telling the browser (and therefore the user):

> You can get the same page, without needing to use JavaScript and without having to load the home page first, if you go directly to this URL.

Making the statement is not enough. You *must* also make that page exist at that URL so that the statement is true.

---

> The thing is, I have a function contact() in the index page( `www.example.com/index.php`) . I want to execute the contact function by accessing this url : `www.example.com/contact`

So you need to:

- Make any request to the site hit your PHP (I'd use Apache ScriptAlias for this, or possibly mod_rewrite) — you might want to exclude requests for images, or move them to another hostname.
- Determine what the URL is inside the PHP
- Call the appropriate function

Comment: The thing is, I have a function contact() in the index page( www.mydomain.com/index.php) . I want to execute the contact function by accessing this url : www.mydomain.com/contact

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I think this is not what I exactly wanted.
http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/state/portfolio
I want something like this link.

Comment: This is exactly how you achieve the effect seen at that link.

Comment: I checked, they using xml files for data storage. its little bit difficult to understand  have any other way?